# Show that $F(\alpha)=F(\sqrt{b^2-4c})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic not $2$ and let $K$ be an extension of $F$ of degree $2$, and let $α ∈ K$ be an element not contained in $F$ such that $\alpha$ a root of polynomial $m_{\alpha}(x) = x^2+bx+c$ where $b,c \in F$ then show that $$F(\alpha)=F(\sqrt{b^2-4c})$$

Since $\alpha$ a root of polynomial $m_{\alpha}(x)$, $$\alpha = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}$$ How do we show  $F(\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2})=F(\sqrt{b^2-4c})$?

Comment: Double inclusion and $$\pm \sqrt{b^2-4c} = 2 \cdot \frac{\pm\sqrt{b^2-4c}-b}{2}+b$$